# Given a list of links, how do I click and validate each one using C# or Protractor, with Selenium?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, jasmine, protractor

Code below is in C#, but I also know javascript/protractor.  Looking for any pattern that works.

```
var links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));           
foreach (var ele in links)
{

    if (ele.Displayed == false) continue;
    if (ele.Enabled) ele.Click();  
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    driver.Navigate().Back();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

}
```

Without the sleep above (which I don't like) the page hasn't settled down enough to Navigate Back.  With the sleep values in, I can click the link, and go back but only one time!  The error on 2nd iteration tells me that [the page is stale](https://www.google.com/search?q=page%20object%20stale&oq=page%20object%20stale&aqs=chrome..69i57.3172j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=page%20object%20stale%20selenium).

**Question:**  Using Selenium with C# or Protractor how do I go through entire list of links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these links are regular links with `href` attributes, you can use [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) to get the array of `href`s, and navigate to each of them one by one. `protractor`-specific solution:

```
element.all(by.tagName("a")).map(function (a) {
    return a.getAttribute("href");
}).then(function (links) {
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
        browser.get(links[i]);
        // TODO: some logic here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I've marked this as the answer.  However in C# I couldn't find the map option so I've also included a C# solution for those who may want to see that.

Answer (score 1):

This solution below works for C# without the MAP option pointed out above. Design was to first find the links and put each element's location and text values into a list named "Locators".  Then for each tuple in that "Locators" list, pull a fresh copy each time before the click and page back methods.

```
        var links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
        var Locators = new List<Tuple<Point, string>>();
        foreach (var thing in links)
        {
            var tup = new Tuple<Point, string>(thing.Location, thing.Text);
            Locators.Add(tup);
        }
        foreach (var thing in Locators)
        {
            var pt = thing.Item1;
            var reassess = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
            var filtered = reassess.ToList<IWebElement>().Where(
                p =>
                    p.Location == thing.Item1 &&
                    p.Text == thing.Item2 &&
                    p.Displayed == true
                    );
            // Debugger.Break();
            if (filtered.Count() == 0) continue;
            filtered.First().Click();
            driver.WaitForPageToLoad();
            AssessNewPageContent();
            driver.Navigate().Back();
            driver.WaitForPageToLoad();
        }
```

The AssessNewPageContent does assertions and could be a callback if you prefer that.

The code for WaitForPageToLoad was lifted from the internet somewhere and looks like this:

```
    public static IWebDriver WaitForPageToLoad(this IWebDriver driver)
    {
        TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);

        IJavaScriptExecutor javascript = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        if (javascript == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("driver", "Driver must support javascript execution");

        wait.Until((d) =>
        {
            try
            {
                string readyState = javascript.ExecuteScript("if (document.readyState) return document.readyState;").ToString();
                return readyState.ToLower() == "complete";
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                //Window is no longer available
                return e.Message.ToLower().Contains("unable to get browser");
            }
            catch (WebDriverException e)
            {
                //Browser is no longer available
                return e.Message.ToLower().Contains("unable to connect");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return driver;
    }
```